# Spring Controller Testing. Can't seem to find MockMvcRequestBuilders

Tags: unit-testing, spring-mvc, junit, integration-testing, spring-test-mvc

I'm trying to write some Unit and Integration tests for my Spring Controllers following  [this guide](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/integration-testing-of-spring-mvc-applications-controllers/) and  [Spring's documentation for testing MVC controllers](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-framework)

The problem is that I'm unable to find the appropriate includes in mvnrepository for the following piece of code

```
 this.mockMvc.perform(get("/foo").accept("application/json"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(content().mimeType("application/json"));
```

I'm unable to find the jar for get("/foo) method and .mimeType(....).

Upon googling, I was however able to find out the source for the above get and mimeType [at here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-test-mvc/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/test/web/server/request/MockHttpServletRequestBuilderTests.java).
So, should I just copy paste these helper classes from this Spring Test showcase project? or am I missing something here?

Comment: Make sure the import is static. import static org.springframework.test.web.server.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;

Comment: @Sparticles So I did try putting in those static imports but the IDE can't seem to be able to find it (locally or in a Maven repo). Does it mean that I need to manually copy over these static classes to my project? That doesn't feel right!

Comment: Your missing the jars, here is a link to maven repo, download the appropriate one and add it to your library. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test

Comment: @Sparticles  I do have the spring-test dependency included. What I need here is MockHttpServletRequestBuilderTests.java which is not in spring-test jar.

Comment: What is the spring version? This feature needs 3.2+ if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Hippoom I've been using 3.2.4.RELEASE. That is why I'm surprised!

Comment: org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Eclipse IDE. Unfortunately it doesn't automatically import static imports.

You have to add these through:  Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Favorites.

Here's a good post with more information:
http://piotrnowicki.com/2012/04/content-assist-with-static-imports-in-eclipse/

Answer (score 7):

Looks like the package name changed from `test.web.server` to `test.web.servlet` in spring-test and the blog articles/docs are out of date for Spring 4.

Comment: This is the answer. Mark it please.

Comment: This is valid answer.

Answer (score 1):

do you have

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

somewhere in your pom.xml?

Comment: Yes. I do have the spring-test dependency included. What I need here is MockHttpServletRequestBuilderTests.java which is not in spring-test jar.

Comment: you should not be forced to add anything manually if you specified dependency in pom.xml

Comment: exactly! That is why I'm confused.

Comment: well, maybe you have some chaos in dependencies then. Take a look at effective pom, it may give you some clue.